# Return the larger value if it is in the range 10..20

Tags: java

I am trying to work out this problem on codingbat and the problem is Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range. The solution has been given below but I can not understand the first part as the comment says larger value is a, but the code says( b > a ) and what does this mean: int temp = a; a = b; b = temp;. Can anyone please explain it...

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  // First make it so the bigger value is in a
  if (b > a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }

  // Knowing a is bigger, just check a first
  if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) return a;
  if (b >= 10 && b <= 20) return b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if a is bigger than b, the first if will be skipped because a is already bigger than bfirst it takes the bigger value in a. then you have to know that once you call a return statement, the rest is skipped. after having the bigger value in a, they check if a is between 10 and 20. if yes, it returns a. otherwise it checks if b is in range. if yes it returns b and if none of them is betweeen 10 and 20, it returns 0

Comment: That first part basically swaps `a` and `b` if `b` is bigger so that `a` is _always_ the bigger value in the following parts. The comment says "Knowing a is bigger..." because the part before made sure that `a` is bigger than or at least equal to `b`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first if statement makes sure that `a` is not smaller than `b` (if `a` is smaller than `b`, it swaps `a` and `b` - that's what the 3 assignment statements involving the `temp` variable do).

The second if statement returns `a` if it's in the required range (and at this point we know `a >= b`).

If not, the third if statement returns `b` if it's in the required range.

Otherwise 0 is returned (when both `a` and `b` are not in the required range).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It says that if the value of `b` is greater than that of `a`, switch the 2 values. So, for example, if `a = 10` and `b = 15`:

`if (b > a) {`  is true so will get in the if

`int temp = a;` temp will take the value 10

`a = b;` a will take the value 15

`b = temp;` b will take the value 10

So, the values of `a` and `b` will be switched, if the value of `b` is greater than that of `a`. Therefore, `a` will have the bigger value.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: the example really helps and I am imaging the temp is a container and you put 10 into it, then assign 15 to a, and assign 10 to b, swap finished.

Comment: `temp` is a variable, just as `a` and `b` are. It is only used inside the `if` statement, in order to swap the two values. Note that instead of `temp`, it could have any name (any name acceptable by Java -- you can find more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), for example, it could be named `c`.